# INSERT INTO not working with my select

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to copy some data from one table to another:

There is a table that has the correct date (AUDITLOG), column TIME but I need to put it in the USER table, column USERS_DATE and associate with the correct user...

The SELECT returns the correct data by itself, I'm having issue using the SELECT INTO statement. My hacked up code below:

```
INSERT INTO users (USERS_DATE) WHERE USERID=U.USERID
(SELECT U.USERID,
       javaTimeStampToDate (L.TIME)
          AS "Last Login"
  FROM COMPANY C,
       USERS U,
       AUDITMAP M,
       AUDITLOG L
 WHERE     C.COMPANYID = U.COMPANYID
       AND U.USERID = M.ROWID
       AND M.AUDITID = L.AUDITID
       AND C.APPLICATION = 'A'
       AND L.NOTES LIKE '%went inactive%'
       AND U.STATUS = 0);
```

Comment: seems like you are looking for an UPDATE with a join not an insert operation.....

Comment: 1. Your columns you are inserting into must match the columns in the select. 2. the WHERE statement on line 1 is bad syntax, remove it. 3. Inserts = new data (new record), UPDATE = modify existing records. You sure you want an insert?

Comment: So the table already has the IDs in it? If so, you need an `update`, not an `insert`. Also - what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Insert into part has one field specified.  Select pulls two.  You can't put two fields into one without combining them.

Comment: You guys are correct, i do need an update, not an insert statement.. I was using the select to pull two because I need to update the time of each user so I need their ID as well as the log time.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But in general: `insert` has no `where` clause

Comment: I am using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query for sql server. 
I think you need an update query. Also change your commas with `JOIN` condition.

```
  UPDATE U
    SET U.USERS_DATE=L.TIME
  FROM COMPANY C 
       JOIN USERS U ON C.COMPANYID = U.COMPANYID
       JOIN AUDITMAP M ON U.USERID = M.ROWID
       JOIN AUDITLOG L ON M.AUDITID = L.AUDITID
 WHERE   C.APPLICATION = 'A'
       AND L.NOTES LIKE '%went inactive%'
       AND U.STATUS = 0
```

use below query for oracle,

```
MERGE INTO USERS U
USING 
(
  SELECT M.ROWID,L.Time
  FROM AUDITMAP M 
       JOIN AUDITLOG L ON M.AUDITID = L.AUDITID
  WHERE L.NOTES LIKE '%went inactive%'
) Au ON (U.USERID = Au.ROWID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET U.USERS_DATE = Au.TIME
WHERE U.STATUS = 0 AND  EXISTS (select 1
                            from COMPANY c
                            where .COMPANYID = U.COMPANYID AND C.APPLICATION = 'A')
```

Comment: Ok, but how does this know which time to associate with each user.. thats why I was selecting USERID as well

Comment: Based on the reference to `SELECT INTO`, it is a reasonable inference that the OP is using SQL Server.  Hence, this seems correct.

Comment: your tables are already linked using required joining conditions. i mean `user` table is joined to `audit log` table by `audit map` using the columns `UserID` and 'AUDITID`. so this will fetch the time against each user from the `audit log` table and update the `Users_date` column in `User` table.

Comment: I tried the above code and it is balking at the FROM statement. I am using Oracle btw.

Comment: Sorry, was out sick yesterday.

Comment: First off, I want to say thank you.. I wouldn't be this close or remotely close without your help! Ok, so I tried the newest code and after fixing the missing c.companyid (I'm assuming you just missed the c) I am getting the following error message: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got ROWID

Comment: I should add that L.Time is a Unix timestamp but I had plan on converting to a regular timestamp using javaTimeStampToDate function.